# Ubuntu 16.04: Where is the network configuration?

Tags: 16.04, networking

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.  In the past, I have always configured my network through the /etc/network/interfaces file but for this install, I have used the 'Edit Connections' option from the Gnome taskbar network menu.  My network is configured and works, but the interfaces file just contains

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

So, where is the actual configuration for the network stored and why is it not in the interfaces file?

Comment: It is stored in Network Manger

Answer (score 14):

If you setup a connection using Network Manager, it is stored in

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/
```

A file for each connection is created there.

Comment: Is it advisable to manually edit those? If not then a note/warning perhaps is a good idea?

Comment: You can edit those manually. I see no problem with that. Some of the setting are not available from GUI.

Comment: In new Network manager it's recommend that won't edit configuration file manually . There are some rich commands for editing persistent NIC configuration . Most common is `nmcli` . In RHCA it suggest that only use `nmcli` for editing NIC profiles . @MichaelBay

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.  I'd still like to know why this tool can't just put this configuration information in the /etc/network/interfaces file.  Why use one way when you can have multiple confusing ways to do the same thing, eh?

Comment: These are different ways of setting network. If you edit `/etc/network/interfaces`, NM will be disabled. Nothing is confusing. For a desktop forget about the `interfaces` file ;-)

Comment: @Speakjava: NetworkManager does much more than set up network interfaces which is beyond the scope of `/etc/network/interfaces`. It would be more confusing to spread out all those settings controlled by a single facility over multiple configuration files of otherwise unrelated legacy subsystems.